# JavaScript link error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using JavaScript to validate email. The problem is, when the email ids don't match, then one alert button will come. Once I click the button it still takes me to the other page, instead of same page to correct my mail id.

HTML:

```
<label for="department">Email ID</label>
<input type="email" size="30" name="email" id="email" required />
<label for="department">Confirm Email ID</label>
<input type="email" size="30" name="cname" id="confirm_email" required />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="button" onClick="validate()">
```

JavaScript:

```
function validate()
{
    if(document.getElementById("email").value != document.getElementById("confirm_email").value)
        alert("Email do no match");
}
```

Comment: try adding a return false when the email doesn't match for blocking the form submit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell the submit button to not perform the submit

```
function validate()
{
      if (document.getElementById("email").value!=document.getElementById("confirm_email").value) {
         alert("Email do no match");
         return false;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `return false;` in your `if` code block if you dont want the redirect.

Its the browser's default to refresh the page when the form is submitted. To prevent this refresh, add `return false;`.

*Learn more:* [`return` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: Why the downvotes? If you are downvoting, please have the courtesy to mention WHY.

Comment: I don't really see how the use of window.location.href is justified here, as ekans suggested, blocking the form submit is most likely what the OP was looking for.

Comment: @Olivier Even my code will block the form submit, PLUS, it will redirect.

Comment: @Olivier Requoting what OP said: `once i click the button it will takes me to the other page not to same page to correct my mail id`. So when the user clicks OK on the alert, it should redirect.

Comment: And if the user clicks a close button on the alert, the page still redirects. **Whatever** the user does, he will be redirected away from the form.

Comment: @Rahul Desai nowhere within that text does the OP state that he actually wishes for a redirect. It's more like he states that it's an error within his issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because You have taken button type=submit

Change input type='button'

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" class="button" onClick="validate()">
```

and submit form using javascript

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

I case you want to validate only on submit then use

```
 event.preventDefault();
```

and then validate but after successful validation you have to submit the form using js or jq. JS method is given above and jq method is:

```
$("form").submit();
```

Comment: i need it in my form submit only . while submitting only it must be validate

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function validate(){
            if(document.getElementById("email").value != document.getElementById("confirm_email").value){
                alert("Email do no match");
                return false;
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="formsubmit.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
            <label for="department">Email ID</label>
            <input type="email" size="30" name="email" id="email" required />
            <label for="department">Confirm Email ID</label>
            <input type="email" size="30" name="cname" id="confirm_email" required />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="button">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below javascript code, your html code is correct!

Well executing the JavaScript code in StackOverflow Script Runner won't run and occur erorrs. If input boxes with email and confirm_email id(s) are declared, this should work.
Hope it could help!

```js
function validate(){
  if(!document.querySelector("#email").value === document.querySelector("#confirm_email").value){
    alert("Email do not match.");
  }
}

/* In JavaScript, the ! keyword before the condition belongs to execute the statement if the given condition is false. */
```

Answer (score -1):

It must prevent the form to get submitted if the validation is failed. so

```
       return validate();
```

must be there. So if the validate function returns a false value then it will stop the form to be submitted. If the validate function return true then the submission will be done.

```
      <form method='post' action='action.php'>      
        <label for="department">Email ID</label>
        <input type="email" size="30" name="email" id="email" required />
        <label for="department">Confirm Email ID</label>
        <input type="email" size="30" name="cname" id="confirm_email" required />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="button" onClick="return validate();">  
      </form>


<script>
    function validateEmail(email) { 
        var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(email);
    } 

     function validate(){
        if(!validateEmail(document.getElementById('email').value))
        {
             alert('Please enter a valid email');
             email.focus();
             return false;
        }
        else if(document.getElementById('email').value!=document.getElementById('confirm_email').value) {
            alert('Email Mismatch');
            confirm_email.focus();
            return false;
        }
            return true;
     }
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Fix that and remove type=submit and use a function or use following code:

```
<script>
function check(){
//* Also add a id "submit" to submit button*//
document.querySelector("#submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
//* Perform your actions when that submit button will be clicked and close with this in next line*//
})</script>
```

Comment: Your code is not syntactically correct, say WHY you are added an ID, no need for`<script>` tag as the format indicates it is code